# How to publish a API project with heroku?

Tags: node.js, api, express, heroku

I try to publish an API application with Heroku but I am getting an error. What could be the reason? I might be doing something missing. Can you show me what I'm missing?

[heroku logs --tail Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epUts.png)

[Application index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xHUl.png)

edit: [image: Script]
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you add `scripts` object from package.json and......Quick suggestion not sure but can you try changing `npm start` command to `node server.js`

Comment: Of course. I add script object

Comment: I changed but not fixed

Comment: your `start` command is says `node socket`, can you also add errors in question after changing it to `node server.js`

Comment: I added image. Can you check for me

Comment: ok seem like earlier issue is resolved,  now it is saying it is not getting `mongouri` undefined, so how you are using MongoUri in application? check this article to set env variables in heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Comment: I cant see mongodb settings. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your code snippet so i'm just giving my example here for local development and heroku setup both

- In local development

  1. install `dotenv` npm package
  2. create `.env` file in root directory and set `MONGOURI='Your mongo string  here'`
  3. then you can import dotenv package in root as shown in below example and use variable as `process.env.MONGOURI`
- On Heroku
  there are multiple ways you can do same thing as above which are listed here in [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). More specifically i'll suggest you to do [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard) way from heroku frontend

```js
require('dotenv').config();  // <-- install `dotenv` package
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const mongoUrl = process.env.MONGOURI;
// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, db) {
   
  if(err) throw err;

  db.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
    console.log("mongo connected");
  });
  
  db.close();
});
```

I had created a node with mongo boilerplate project to get me started you can check if you want [node-auth-mongo](https://github.com/rohit-ambre/node-auth-mongo)

Comment: it is my source code 
https://github.com/ozgunmustafa/nodejs-api
Can you check for me ?

Comment: by looking at your code, you're already using `dotenv` but I think you have ignored `./config/env` file in gitignore sp i'll suggest you to create an example env file as `.env.example` and add example config data and push it then on server create `.env` file from that file and start your application, can you try this